# power bi how to order dates in line and stacked column chart where dates are not unique

Tags: powerbi

example data behind this visual is as follows:

```
Order Date         team  count
1      Jan-20      A     6
2      Feb-20      A     7
3      Feb-20      B     10
4      Mar-20      A     8
:
80     Dec-20      A      12
```

The date is stored in text format then I have added an index so in the chart the dates are ordered on the x axis. But as the date is not unique in the data the dates are not ordered on the x axis.

How can I get the dates ordered from Jan-Dec

Comment: I also added a new column, ordering the months, so this is a unique order per month. But this still didn't help achieve the desired result, I would appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

You could create a separate sorting table. First, add a new column to existing table:

```
Month = LEFT([Date], 3)
```

Then create a new table, let's call it SortTable:

```
Month | Sort
Jan   | 1
Feb   | 2
...
Dec   | 12
```

Then set the SortingTable Month to sort by column Sort. Lastly, set a relation between the tables from Orders[Month] to SortTable[Month] and use SortTable[Month] on the graph x axis.

Comment: I tried what you mentioned but this has not allowed me to order the month on the x axis as desired. For each column in the two tables above what should the data types be?

Comment: Month-field in both tables should be text, Sort-field should be a number. Could you describe what went wrong, did this change anything? What sort of settings you have on the chart? Make sure you have set the chart to sort by months.